# mysql stored procedure Declare error in Dbeaver

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

I am not able to run the MySQL stored procedures in Dbeaver script window.
Below is my sample code which i am getting error

```
delimiter //
create procedure sp_cppo_Oracle_Assignment(
    IN clntCode VARCHAR(200),
    IN clntName VARCHAR(200),
    IN pgCode VARCHAR(200),
    IN pgName VARCHAR(200),
    IN prjCode VARCHAR(200),
    IN prjName VARCHAR(200),
    IN startDate date,
    IN endDate date,
    IN proportion int,
    IN userData Json
) BEGIN DECLARE oracleExists INT;
DECLARE prjID, i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE ids_length INT DEFAULT 0; DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
      ROLLBACK;
      SELECT 'Fail';
    END;
    START TRANSACTION; SET i=0;  
  SELECT 'Succcessss step1';
  Call sp_cppo_insert_cpp(clntCode, clntName, pgCode, pgName, prjCode,prjName);
  select 'Success-1';
  SET prjID = (select ProjectID from CPPO_Project where ProjectCode = prjCode);  
  select 'Success-2';
    -- Retrieve values from JSON
  SET @ids_length = JSON_LENGTH(JSON_EXTRACT(userData, '$.assignees'));
  select 'Success-3';
  WHILE i < @ids_length DO
  select 'Success-4';
      SET @oracleId = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(userData, CONCAT('$.assignees[',i,'].oracleId')));
      select 'Success-5';
      SET oracleExists= (select EmployeeID from CPPO_EmployeeAssignments
        where EmployeeID = @oracleId and ProjectID = prjID);
        select 'Success-6';
      insert into CPPO_EmployeeAssignments(ProjectID, EmployeeID, StartDate, EndDate, Proportion, Active, Created_By) 
      values(prjID, @oracleId, startDate, endDate, proportion, 1,'Admin');
    select 'Success-7';
      SELECT i + 1 INTO i;
  END WHILE;
  select 'Success-8';
COMMIT;
SELECT 'Success';
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I am receiving the below error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN clntCode VARCHAR(200),
>     IN clntName VARCHAR(200),
>     IN pgCode VA' at line 2

AS i am new to Mysql, not able to understand the exact error.
I am good with Sql server.

One difficulty I find with SQL is that some errors are very unspecific, which constitutes an added challenge to a beginner... It's probably something basic but I can't see it.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error in the regular MySQL command-line client, so it seems specific to DBeaver. It may not need you to use `DELIMITER`.

Comment: That is weird I don't see the typo .. ok I have the best solution for you, try to create the stored procedure in MySQL Workbench, it highlights goofs in real time so you can see them before you even execute the command.  Plus its Free and works in nearly all main OS that exists.    Download here -->
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Comment: There is no error you your procedure, like Barmar mentioned it is likely something on DBeaver.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to highlight the entire code block and then run it.
The issue is DBeaver is not able to handle the more complex operations, such as creating stored procedures, as easily as other clients.
Solution from here: https://dbeaver.io/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1170

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34216724)